# C# Dictionary ArrayList Count

Tags: c#, dictionary, arraylist

Is there an easy way to get a count on the values of a specific dictionarys keys values?

```
static void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, ArrayList> SpecTimes = new Dictionary<string, ArrayList>;
    ArrayList times = new ArrayList();
    string count = "";

    times.Add = "000.00.00";
    times.Add = "000.00.00";
    times.Add = "000.00.00";

   string spec = "A101";

   SpecTimes.Add(spec,times);

   count = SpecTimes[spec].values.count;
}
```

Comment: That looks like half C# and half... I don't know.

Comment: Do not use `ArrayList`s.  Instead, use `List<T>`

Comment: Why are you mixing generic collections and non-generic collections? And not using brackets in your method calls? Please show *real* code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but this should be close to what you need.

```
static void Main()
{
  Dictionary<string, List<string>> SpecTimes = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
  List<string> times = new List<string>();
  int count = 0;

  times.Add = "000.00.00";
  times.Add = "000.00.00";
  times.Add = "000.00.00";

  string spec = "A101";

  SpecTimes.Add(spec,times);

  // check to make sure the key exists, otherwise you'll get an exception.
  if(SpecTimes.ContainsKey(spec))
  {
      count = SpecTimes[spec].Count;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some errors in your code, so it would not compile anyway. You should change it like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    IDictionary<string, IList<string>> specTimes = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();
    IList<string> times = new List<string>();

    times.Add("000.00.00");
    times.Add("000.00.00");
    times.Add("000.00.00");

    string spec = "A101";
    specTimes.Add(spec, times);

    int count = specTimes[spec].Count;
}
```

Since you already get the number of occurences, what is the problem anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't going to compile as is, and you shouldn't be using ArrayList, but rather `List<T>` (as SLaks pointed out.) That being said, `List<T>` has a `Count` property, so `SpecTime[key].Count` should work just fine (assuming key is actually in the dictionary.)

Comment: I know that you meant to say `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` has a `Count` property.

Comment: @Rick It does, but why would that be what I mean?

Comment: Reading too fast.  Mea culpa. (`SpecTime.Count` vs. `SpecTime[key].Count`)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 3.5 and above, use Linq for this:

```
var count = (from s in SpecTimes where SpecTimes.Key == <keyword> select s).Count();
```

anyway, as everyone suggested, you should choose `List<string>` over `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

If using .NET 3.5 you can use Linq to filter and count. However avoid ArrayList if possible, and use generics.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> SpecTimes = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        List<string> times = new List<string>();
        int count;

        times.Add("000.00.00");
        times.Add("000.00.00");
        times.Add("000.00.00");
        times.Add("000.00.01");

        string spec = "A101";

        SpecTimes.Add(spec,times);

        // gives 4
        count = SpecTimes[spec].Count;

        // gives 3
        count = (from i in SpecTimes[spec] where i == "000.00.00" select i).Count();

        // gives 1
        count = (from i in SpecTimes[spec] where i == "000.00.01" select i).Count();
    }
```